# How is this query string handled by Web Api?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, query-string

2020-05-09?symbols=HKD&base=CAD is a query string that retrieves the exchange rate between those two currencies at that specific date in a public API. I know that the first part of the string is supposed to be the Action of the Controller and the rest the parameters. But how is this type of query string handled by APIs? They generate a new Action every day? thats hard to bealive...

```
 public class RatesController : ApiController
{        

    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to create a new action each day. The date value is a route param.
You can achieve that with this code:

```
    public class RateModel
    {
        [FromRoute]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [FromQuery]
        public string Symbols { get; set; }
        [FromQuery]
        public string Base { get; set; }
    }

...
        [HttpGet("rate/{date}")]
        public ActionResult Get(RateModel model)
        {
            return Ok(model);
        }
```

And then calling GET method on `~/rate/2020-05-09?symbols=HKD&base=CAD`

Will return:

```
{
  "date": "2020-05-09T00:00:00",
  "symbols": "HKD",
  "base": "CAD"
}
```